# Pytorch backward does not compute the gradients for requested variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to train a resnet18 model on pytorch (+pytorch-lightning) with the use of Virtual Adversarial Training. During the computations required for this type of training I need to obtain the gradient of *D* (ie. the cross-entropy loss of the model) with regard to tensor *r*.

This should, in theory, happen in the following code snippet:

```
def generic_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx, step_type):
    x, y = train_batch
    unlabeled_idx = y is None

    d = torch.rand(x.shape).to(x.device)
    d = d/(torch.norm(d) + 1e-8)

    pred_y = self.classifier(x)
    y[unlabeled_idx] = pred_y[unlabeled_idx]
    l = self.criterion(pred_y, y)
    R_adv = torch.zeros_like(x)
    for _ in range(self.ip):
        r = self.xi * d
        r.requires_grad = True
        pred_hat = self.classifier(x + r)
        # pred_hat = F.log_softmax(pred_hat, dim=1)
        D = self.criterion(pred_hat, pred_y)
        self.classifier.zero_grad()
        D.requires_grad=True
        D.backward()
        R_adv += self.eps * r.grad / (torch.norm(r.grad) + 1e-8)

    R_adv /= 32
    loss = l + R_adv * self.a
    loss.backward()
    self.accuracy[step_type] = self.acc_metric(torch.argmax(pred_y, 1), y)
    return loss
```

Here, to my understanding, `r.grad` should in theory be the gradient of *D* with respect to *r*. However, the code throws this at `D.backward()`:

`RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`
(full traceback excluded because this error is not helpful and technically "solved" as I know the cause for it, explained just below)

After some research and debugging it seems that in this situation `D.backward()` attempts to calculate dD/dD disregarding any previous mention of `requires_grad=True`. This is confirmed when I add `D.requires_grad=True` and I get `D.grad=Tensor(1.,device='cuda:0')` but `r.grad=None`.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are trying to do. `_requires_grad = True` does not accomplish anything here; `requires_grad` is a flag applied to leaf tensors -- non-leaf tensors inherit this flag from their arguments (ancestors in the computational graph), making it redundant for both `r` and `D`.

Comment: As I said on the post I'm trying to get the gradient of `D` with regard to `r` (dD/dr). I understand that `D.requires_grad` is redundant and I said so already. As for `r.grad`, why would it be redundant? How else would I get that value?

Comment: `requires_grad` is redundant, not `grad`. How is `self.xi` defined? You have in essence a leaf tensor `d` that doesn't require grad, which is what's probably causing `r` to also be gradless.

Comment: self.xi is a scalar hyperparameter of the model (a simple float if you will) that should not affect anything. To my understanding you're saying that d should require the gradient?

Comment: well if `self.xi` is a constant that doesn't require grad, and `d` is random, `r` is a "constant" for the backward engine, meaning that you're trying to differentiate between `pred_hat` and `pred_hat + r`, which is indeed 1 (assuming that `criterion` doesn't carry any differentiable parameters itself), hence my confusion on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I **guess** you are missing some adversarial parameters from which you should be sampling `d`  from?

Comment: Well, this is starting to stray a bit from the original question but these calculations are straight from the relevant paper (don't know if I can make citations here). One possibly missing line of code is the update `d = r` at the end of this deal. Also, `dD/dconstant` should mathematically be equal to `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lightning, `.backward()` and optimizer step are all handled under the hood. If you do it yourself like in the code above, it will mess with Lightning because it doesn't know you called backward yourself.

You can enable manual optimization in the LightningModule:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # put this in your init
    self.automatic_optimization = False
```

This tells Lightning that you are taking over calling backward and handling optimizer step + zero grad yourself. Don't forget to add that in your code above. You can access the optimizer and scheduler like so in your training step:

```py
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):

    optimizer = self.optimizers()
    scheduler = self.lr_schedulers()

    # do your training step
    # don't forget to call:
    # 1) backward 2) optimizer step 3) zero grad
```

Read more about manual optimization [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model/manual_optimization.html?highlight=manual%20optimiztion).